# Как открыть текстовый файл для чтения занятый другой программой?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! У меня проблема... Мне нужно открыть текстовый файл `xxx.log` (журнал событий), который занят другой программой и вывести все содержимое или в `МЕМО` или `RICHEDIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделать копию и ее прочитать

Comment: @korok ИМХО действительно правильное решение. 

Comment: Разница какая? Если файл не удается открыть на чтение, его нельзя скопировать.

Comment: Открыть файл не удаеться так как наверное он используеться в монопольном доступе а скопировать удаеться.

Answer (score 1):

Работа с файлами в Windows. Смотря в каком режиме файл открыт другими программами. Если, например, для чтения, то тебе ничего не мешает также открыть для чтения и прочитать. Если файл открыт в монопольном доступе, тут уже ничего не поделашь, кроме как принудительно освободить данный файл от чужих программ (уничтожить все дескрипторы).
См. WinAPI функцию [CreateFile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35201/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9).